# Using hypertarget caption in hyperlink caption

Tags: hyperref

I want to use hypertarget caption in hyperlink caption automatically.

Example:

```
\hypertarget{myTarget}{My Target}

See \hyperlink{myTarget}{\useMyTargetCaption}.
```

Wanted result:

My Target

See *My Target*.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can redefine `\hypertarget` so that it defines a new command corresponding to its first argument:

```
\let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand{\hypertarget}[2]{%
  \oldhypertarget{#1}{#2}%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \string\expandafter\string\gdef
          \string\csname\string\detokenize{#1}\string\endcsname{#2}%
    }%
  }
```

In this way, when you issue

```
\hypertarget{myTarget}{My Target}
```

this also saves a command named `\myTarget` in the `.aux` file.

Then we define a new command `\myhyperlink` that takes care of that:

```
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\csname #1\endcsname}%
  }
```

When you issue

```
\myhyperlink{myTarget}
```

this results in

```
\hyperlink{myTarget}{\myTarget}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand{\hypertarget}[2]{%
  \oldhypertarget{#1}{#2}%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \string\expandafter\string\gdef
          \string\csname\string\detokenize{#1}\string\endcsname{#2}%
    }%
  }
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\csname #1\endcsname}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{myTarget}{My Target}

See \myhyperlink{myTarget}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to customize it, you can change it, for example, to (requires `xcolor` package`):

```
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{cyan}{\textit{\csname #1\endcsname}}}%
  }
```

and the result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As in this case, how to add spaces to label's name?

Comment: @Supert I misunderstood. Now the answer is completely different.

Comment: Yes, but there is a bug: if you place link before target, link will be empty.

Comment: As far as I can see, myLink is trying to call myTarget.csname before it is defined

Comment: If we return back to your previous answer, how we can add spaces to label's name? Well, it is workaround, but it is better than disappearing ninja links.

Comment: @Supert In the old answer it was showing the label, not the text, so there's no chance to print a space.

Comment: that's bad. Any idea to make
'See \myhyperlink{myTarget}.
\hypertarget{myTarget}{My Target}'
work?

Comment: @Supert Now it should work fine.

Comment: @Supert You're welcome. It took me some time, but at the end I've found a working solution :-)

Comment: Can I deduce from this that the links implemented with \hypertarget and \hyperlink do NOT add anything to the .aux file? That is, they employ some internal mechanism within the PDF itself?