# Hyperlinking conditions with math symbols error

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, conditionals

I have this code borrowed from a similar stack thread

```
\newcounter{susis}

\newcommand{\myHyperlink}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{susis}\label{susislink#1}%
\ifcsname r@susistarget#1\endcsname
\hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}%
\else
\hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#2}}%
\fi
}

\newcommand{\myHypertarget}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{susis}\label{susistarget#1}%
\ifcsname r@susislink#1\endcsname
\hypertarget{#1}{\textcolor{teal}{#2}}%
\else
\hypertarget{#1}{\fbox{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}%
\fi
}
```

And it works when I run `\myHyperlink{Hello}{Hello}`. However, when I try to do `\myHyperlink{\lor}{\lor}` (logical OR symbol), it says: `Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \lor`.

How would I fix this error?

Additional info: I'm trying to target and link math operators. It works with normal hypertarget and hyperlink, but I want to include the additional feature: if the link refers to an undeclared target, it would display in red text instead of blue.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `\lor` is math expression, so it should be in math environment: `$\lor$`. if this influence on working of your hyper links, i cant test (you not provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired functionality can be accomplished by combining these answers:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168835/143704

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30484/143704

Answer (score 1):

You need to employ the directive in the form

```
\myHyperlink{lor}{$\lor$}
```

Two general recommendations:

- The first argument should be a simple string -- no macros of any kind
- If the second argument is a math-mode command, such as `\lor`, you need to employ math mode to typeset it, i.e., surround `\lor` with `$` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\newcounter{susis}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myHyperlink}[2]{%
   \refstepcounter{susis}\label{susislink#1}%
   \ifcsname r@susistarget#1\endcsname
      \hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}%
   \else
      \hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#2}}%
   \fi
}
\newcommand{\myHypertarget}[2]{%
   \refstepcounter{susis}\label{susistarget#1}%
   \ifcsname r@susislink#1\endcsname
      \hypertarget{#1}{\textcolor{teal}{#2}}%
   \else
      \hypertarget{#1}{\fbox{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}%
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\myHyperlink{Hello}{Hello} \myHypertarget{Hello}{Hello}

\myHyperlink{lor}{$\lor$} \myHypertarget{lor}{$\lor$}

\myHyperlink{good1}{Good1} \myHypertarget{good2}{Good2}

\myHyperlink{wedge}{$\wedge$} \myHypertarget{dots}{$\dots$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm aware that it's discouraged to use macros to for hyperref, but aren't there any workarounds? targeting and linking works perfectly if where weren't any `\ifcsname`s around.

Edit: And my notes is full of \land, \lor, \implies, \lnot, etc. and every time I call these things, I want to link them to the original target. It would be very difficult if for each call of \lor, i had to link{lor}{\lor}, instead of simply link{\lor}

Comment: @japseow - Both user-level macros contain the instruction `\label{susislink#1}`. Some "TeX-special" characters are allowed in the argument of `\label` -- but not all. In particular, the backslash character isn't allowed. Similarly, the directive `\ifcsname r@susistarget#1\endcsname` only works if `#1` doesn't contain a backslash character.  It's for these reasons that one a LaTeX macro that contains a backslash isn't allowed in the first argument of either `\myHyperlink}` or `\myHypertarget}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an approach with an optional argument for the internal name; if it's present, it is used; otherwise, the mandatory argument is used.

However, you need to use `$` around `\lor`, because it's an inherently mathematical command.

The internal name is “stringified” and suitable protection is added around it in the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=5cm,
  paperheight=5cm,
  vmargin=2mm,
  hmargin=0.5cm,
  includehead,includefoot
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse,hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\newcounter{susis}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myHyperlink}{ O{#2}m }
 {
  \japseow_hyperlink:nn { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myHypertarget}{ O{#2}m }
 {
  \japseow_hypertarget:nn { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \japseow_hyperlink:nn
 {
  \refstepcounter{susis}\label{susislink\protectlabel{#1}}
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { r@susistarget#1 }
   {
    \hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}
   }
   {
    \hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#2}}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \japseow_hypertarget:nn
 {
  \refstepcounter{susis}\label{susistarget\protectlabel{#1}}
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { r@susislink#1 }
   {
    \hypertarget{#1}{\textcolor{teal}{#2}}
   }
   {
    \hypertarget{#1}{\fbox{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}
   }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\protectlabel{m}
 {
  \tl_to_str:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myHyperlink{Hello}\clearpage

\myHypertarget{Hello}\clearpage

\myHyperlink{$\lor$}\clearpage

\myHypertarget{$\lor$}\clearpage

\myHyperlink[weird]{This is too weird for using as a link}\clearpage

\myHypertarget[weird]{Good2}\clearpage

\myHypertarget[ops]{Whatever}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow it works! But, I'm having a problem in my `\begin{tcolorbox} \begin{align} ... \end{align} \end{tcolorbox}`. I'm getting: `Multiple \label's: label 'susistarget\protectlabel {unusedlabed}' will be lost.` whenever I try to use the myHypertarget within the tcolorbox and align

Comment: It seems to happen when I have a hypertarget and hyperlink at the same line (even if the link doesn't refer to the target)

Comment: @japseow With `align` it's a very different thing, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in LaTex, but will this solution work?

I create a dynamic array/arraylist of strings. Whenever I create a new hypertarget, I add the "string-ified" input into the arraylist.

Then when I call a new hyperlink, it checks if the stringified input is contained in the arraylist. If not, color it red instead of blue.

Though, I don't even have a clue on how to implement it.