# '\label' in 'align*' environment without marginal tag

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath

I want to be able to refer to an equation in an `align*` environment using a hyperlink, but in labeling the equation, I don't want there to be a visible tag.

The following code is almost what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  x \tag{x}\label{x}
\end{align*}

test: \ref{x}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]
but I don't want the '(x)' tag to be visible.

Is there an easy way to remove this with `align*`, or do I need to use a different environment?

Comment: It might be possible to use a `\hypertarget`; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168832 for ideas.  (Whether embedding a `\hypertarget` in display math will work, I can't say; never tried it.)

Comment: Yes, switching from `\label` to `\hypertarget` fixed my problem, thank you! I'll leave this question open just in case someone knows the answer to it as originally stated.

Comment: Off topic.  `align` or `align* (or any other environment meant for a multi-line display) shouldn't be used for a one-line display.  The spacing above and below is measured differently.

Comment: It's just a one-line display for my MWE. Where I'm actually using this is in a multi-line display, as intended.