# Why does this custom "mytarget/mylink" definition pair NOT work properly?

Tags: hyperref, labels, hypertarget, crossreftools

The goal is to get a pair of commands, `\mytarget(*)` and `\mylink`/`\Mylink`. Specifically, I am interested ***why* "my" solution does NOT work, and how to fix it** (if possible).

---

**Syntax**

- `\mytarget{<label name>}{<Text to display>}`

  `\mytarget*{<label name>}{<Text to display>}`
- `\mylink{<label name>}{<Text to instead display / could be empty>}`

  `\mylink{<label name>}{<Text to instead display / could be empty>}`

**Usage**

1. The command `\mytarget` is intended as an **anchor** that can be referenced before/after its usage in document.

   - Unstarred version, `\mytarget`, is also part of the text. For example, `bla bla \mytarget{label name here}{123} uh uh` should give `bla bla 123 uh uh`, and the "123" part could be referenced earlier/later by `\mylink`/`\Mylink`.
   - Starred version, `\mytarget*`, is ***not*** part of the text. So `bla bla \mytarget*{label name here}{123} uh uh` should give `bla bla uh uh`, and the "123" part could be referenced earlier/later by `\mylink`/`\Mylink`. Notice there is no "123" visible here.
2. The commands `\mylink`/`\Mylink` display the links to a corresponding `\mytarget`.

   - For example, `bla bla \mytarget*{label name here}{123} uh uh \mylink{label name here}{}` would yield `bla bla uh uh 123`. The "123" part here is a **link** to the spot between "bla bla" and "uh uh". (Of course, this example is ridiculous and, of course, in reality the link leads to the line itself).
   - If the second argument for `\mylink{}{}`/`\Mylink{}{}` is given, it should **override** the original second argument of `\mytarget(*)`. For instance, `bla bla \mytarget*{label name here}{123} uh uh \mylink{label name here}{654}` should give `bla bla uh uh 654`. The "654" part is again a link.
   - The difference between `\mylink`/`\Mylink` is that `\mylink` is faithful to the second argument of `\mytarget(*){}{}`. Whereas `\Mylink` does everything the same way **expect** `\Mylink` capitalises the first letter of the second argument. So `bla bla \mytarget*{label name here}{turtle} uh uh \mylink{label name here}{}` would give `bla bla uh uh turtle`; whereas `bla bla \mytarget*{label name here}{turtle} uh uh \Mylink{label name here}{}` yields `bla bla uh uh Turtle`. Notice that "turtle" is capitalised to "Turtle" in the second case. In both cases, "turtle" and "Turtle" are links.

---

**Effort**

Based on helpful comments from [Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn), I was led to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421852/116907) and package [`crossreftools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/crossreftools). Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\mytarget}{\@ifstar{\@mytargetstar}{\@mytargetnostar}}
    \newcommand{\@mytargetstar}[2]{\crtcrossreflabel*{#2}[#1]\@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}}
    \newcommand{\@mytargetnostar}[2]{\crtcrossreflabel{#2}[#1]\@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}}

    \DeclareRobustCommand{\mylink}[2]{%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
            \crtnameref{#1}
        \else
            \crthyperlink{#1}{#2}
        \fi
        \@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}
        }
    
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\Mylink}[2]{%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
            \crtunameref{#1}
        \else
            \crthyperlink{#1}{\MakeUppercase #2}
        \fi
        \@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    a b c \mytarget*{anchor}{I0--I1} d e f
    
    \newpage
    Why doesn't the link of \mylink{anchor}{ullallaa} lead anywhere?

\end{document}
```

**Problems with my effort**

1. Why doesn't the link of `\mylink{anchor}{ullallaa}` lead anywhere?
2. (Not compulsory) Should I change the remaining three `newcommand`s into `\DeclareRobustCommands`?
3. (Not compulsory) Is there a better way to get rid of spaces than putting `\@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}` everywhere?

---

> I am running `pdflatex` 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MikTeX 21.3), and every package in my local distrubution was updated on 28/04/2021. Output is identical (in terms of errors, and what link doesn't work without the 3 packages) on Overleaf with default settings.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124110/discussion-on-question-by-linear-christmas-why-does-this-custom-mytarget-mylink).

Comment: There is a similar question: [Using hypertarget caption in hyperlink caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168832/116907). But it is also different: it displays the target text where the target is set. Whereas it would be invisible in this question. (adding back promised link)

Answer (score 1):

At some time your question was readable but with all the edits you are overstressing me.

I guess you are looking for \nameref, so something like this (without all the stars and variants):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytarget[2]{\phantomsection\NR@gettitle{#2}\label{#1}#2}
\newcommand\mylink[1]{\nameref{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mytarget{blub}{TARGET}

\newpage
\mylink{blub}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. While 1 of the 2 large edits was to reopen the question, I take responsibility for the large number of edits & the length of the quesiton. Apologies. 1. If I were to choose a spec. variant, the one with the ``\mytarget{blub}{TARGET}`` invisible would be most helpful. 2. I am still very interested in why my MWE is faulty. May I ask you to take a look? As a first approximation, you may ignore everything about what its aim is to do. Instead, maybe there is something that an experienced user like yourself would immediately say is wrong/unrecommended on a cursory glance?

Comment: sorry no I don't the time to debug your code. But my "cursory" impression is that it is much to complicated. You want to reference a text in another place and create a link and have a few optional arguments. All this are standard things, and there shouldn't be a need for such convoluted code.

Comment: That's okay. No worries. Unfortunately, that also means we are worlds apart. I do not even understand why the code is "convoluted". If one wants a ``\command`` and ``\command*``, the standard option is to use ``\@ifstar`` (which I have). That requires the commands inside to be ``@``-protected (so I define interim commands ``\@labeltextstarred`` and ``\@labeltext``) which I turn into ``\mytarget*`` and ``\mytarget``, respectively (also standard afaik). (1/2)

Comment: Next I define ``\mylink`` and ``\Mylink`` with a possibility of empty argument. So I use the "classical" approach: ``\if\relax\detokenize{#num}\relax ... \else ... \fi`` approach. Finally, there are cases where an extra space is added, namely when one does something like ``bla bla \mylink{}{} bla bla`` (notice space after ``\mylink``). To account for this possibility, I use (again standard, afaik) ``\apptocmd{\mylink}{\@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}}{}{}`` which checks if the next character is a ``\space``(and removes). I could join some parts together but would it be easier to understand?

Comment: (2/2) :) + Extra: May I ask you to point to a specific part of the code which is "convoluted"? Perhaps I can do something then (on my own) to try to improve that part. (Of course, this would be another edit :)).

Comment: If I wanted to create a starred command I would use \NewDocumentCommand and the the s argument specifier. And I would certainly never define a command that I have to patch two  lines later with `\apptocmd`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did not understand how to use ``\NewDocumentCommand`` but I did try to incorporate your second suggestion. If you have the patience, you may glance at the code again (and updated form of questions). I sincerely apologise in advance if the edit made some things worse. I can roll it back; just let me know in a comment.

Comment: well I took a short look at your last code and it doesn't work because you mix up label names and destination names. There are not the same. But I don't want to did into crossreftools correct this, imho using the hyperref commands directly should be quite enough.

Comment: Could you be more specific? If my error is that fundamental, howcome ``\mylink{anchor}{}`` works and ``\mylink{anchor}{ullallaa}`` doesn't?

Comment: because in the first case you use `\crtnameref` and in the second `\crthyperlink{#1}{#2}`,  and the second use is wrong. #1 should be destination name not a label name. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553769/2388

Comment: Hooray! Now I at least understand a tiny bit of something! I will try to fix this if I can, and then return :)

Comment: It seems that ``\crthyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{#2}`` instead of ``\crthyperlink{#1}{#2}`` fixes the problem! Apparently, I cannot give umlauted characters ``öäü`` (or chr. ``õ``) as the second argument of ``\Mylink{}{}`` but can give for ``\mylink{}{}``. Thus I conclude this is only because ``\MakeUpperCase`` breaks down. Is that correct?

Comment: Package ``xspace`` and its ``\xspace`` is a good substitute for ``\@ifnextchar\space{\hspace{-1sp}}{}`` business, it seems. This answers part 3 (non-compulsory question).

Comment: I never use xspace and its author doesn't recommend it either https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/2388

Comment: 1. It worked for me :). I am not convinced that using it (``xspace``) is harmful, especially after the updates to the package. My problem was also an *additional* space (not a missing or forgotten space as in mentioned link). 2. By the way, would you consider commenting on the non-compulsory part, part 2 (changing ``newcommand``s into ``DeclareRobustcommand``)? 3. After that, I would propose an edit to your answer (with info from comments and my working effort) so I could award the bounty. Currently, the answer by itself does not answer the OP (including previous versions before any edit).

Comment: I don't need a bounty. Please don't edit my answer and change its sense. I don't want to have to review it.

Comment: That's fair enough, thanks for replying. I do not wish to pressure you into anything at all. It simply means (because I will only accept posts that are direct answers to OP (or previous versions)) that 1) I will probably post my own answer; 2) accept that "my" answer; 3) bounty cannot be awarded. I intend no malice; I thought it was polite to let you know before moving forward. Thank you for all your help in comments regardless!